# I need to change the color of the icon on text input focus

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to incorporate a form focus feature where it changes the 
color of each icon when you focus on that specific field

```
<div id="rightside">
            <div th:replace="fragments/loginform">
            <form method="post" id="login" th:object="${credential}">
     <p id="errors" class="warning" role="alert">
            <span th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('*')}" th:utext="${err}"/>
        </p>      
     <p id="block">

       <label for="username" class="has-feedback"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>   

       <span th:if="${openIdLocalId}">
                <strong>
                    <span th:utext="${openIdLocalId}"/>
                </strong>
                <input type="hidden"
                       id="username"
                       name="username"
                       th:value="${openIdLocalId}"/>
            </span>

            <span th:unless="${openIdLocalId}">
                <input class="required textinput has-feedback"
                       placeholder="UH Username"
                       id="username"
                       size="14"
                       tabindex="1"
                       type="text"
                       th:field="*{username}"
                       th:accesskey="#{screen.welcome.label.netid.accesskey}"
                       autocomplete="off"
                       autocapitalize="off"
                       autocorrect="off"
                       required="required"
                       autofocus="autofocus"
                />
            </span>
       </p> 

      <p id="block">
        <label for="password" class="fontawesome-lock"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></label> 

                <input class="required textinput"                       
                       placeholder="Password"
                       type="password"
                       id="password"
                       name="password"
                       size="14"
                       tabindex="2"
                       th:accesskey="#{screen.welcome.label.password.accesskey}"
                       th:field="*{password}"
                       autocomplete="off"
                       required="required"                   
                 />                                     
      </p>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#rightside {
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}
#rightside h3 {
    font-size: 110%;
}
#rightside a {
    display: block;
}
#rightside input.textinput {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
#rightside input.textinput:focus {
    outline-width: 0;
}
#rightside form label {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
    border: solid 1px #CCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 15%;
    height: 50px;
}
#rightside form input[type="text"] {
    float: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 3%;
    width: 77%;
    height: 50px;
}
#rightside form input[type="password"] {
    float: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 3%;
    width: 77%;
    height: 50px;
}
#rightside form input[type="submit"] {
    float: left;
    background: #e1e1e1;
    width: 99%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #978257;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    font-weight: 600;
}
#rightside form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #b6985a;
    color: #fff;
}
```

When the user focuses on either text field, the font-awesome icon pertaining to that input field should change color.  Any help would be great!  Thanks!  CSS only would be preferable, but a js would work too

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and made a codepen for you to show you the value of the following blog post:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/highlight-related-label-when-input-in-focus/

Here's what it offers:

```
$("form :input").focus(function() {
  $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").addClass("labelfocus");
}).blur(function() {
  $("label").removeClass("labelfocus");
});
```

The above utilizes jQuery and it works well as a conceptual example.

http://codepen.io/MassDebates/pen/ZBaVJL

If you wanted to do something that leverages `CSS`'s `:focus` then I would suggest you change your markup to allow something like a sibling (`~`), adjacent/following sibling (`+`) or even a `descendant selector` if you wrap your `input` in the `label`.

The key here is to associate your `label`'s icon (`<i>`) with your `input` element.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with `:focus` and `:blur` pseudo-classes

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".username").focus(function(){
        $(".fa-user").css("color","red");
        console.log("in");
    }).blur(function() {
        $(".fa-user").css("color","yellow");
        console.log('out');
    });

    $(".password").focus(function(){
        $(".fa-lock").css("color","red");
        console.log("in");
    }).blur(function() {
        $(".fa-lock").css("color","yellow");
        console.log('out');
    });


});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/czs3sy0a/2/

Answer (score 0):

I have created a pen that sets a highlighted class on the parent p, and colors the icon using this CSS:

```
p.highlighted .fa {color: red;}
```

And this JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').focusin(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass('highlighted');
    });
    $('input').focusout(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('highlighted');
    });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pNdqYP

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure css solution you can use. As we know we dont have any way to select parent element along with css but we can get the next sibling element with the '+' selector. So what i have done is placed the label containing the icon right after the input that will change it's color when focused using the css `:focus` pseudo element along with the '+' selector of css to get the icon in the label next to the input focused.

In order to set the positions correctly after moving the labels in front of the inputs. I changed the input and label css class from `float:left` to `float:right`. This aligned them where label came before input and the width percentage i changed from 77% to 75% just to keep the responsiveness correct on smaller screens. Below is the sample code.

Sample Code: http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/VmrgWw

Hope this helps you and any future coders who do not want work with a JS code solution.